# IEnumerable<T> filtering

Tags: c#

Let's assume I have objects like below:

System:

```
public class SystemDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public RegionDto Region { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDto Application { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Application:

```
public class ApplicationDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Region:

```
public class RegionDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's assume I have `IEnumerable<SystemDto>`
I would like to query this object under different conditions:

1. By `RegionDto.Name`
2. By `IEnumerable<RegionDto.Name>`
3. By `IEnumerable<RegionDto.Name>` and `IEnumerable<ApplicationDto.Name>`
4. By `RegionDto.Name` and `IEnumerable<ApplicationDto.Name>`
5. By `RegionDto.Name` and `ApplicationDto.Name`

I could write other conditions but I think you got my point. Conditions increase when the amount of fields in `SystemDto` increases.
My question is what should the filter method look like? I don't think having one method which have all parameters is good idea because it may happen that I will have to put `null` for unwanted fields and then in the body check if it was provided or not. Also it will have a lot of lines when I have an object with 20 or more fields.

-- EDIT

@Henric I think your answer is what I need but I have one issue. I have IRepository and IService interfaces. I don't wand to pull all records from data source and filter it just before it will be used. If I would like to filter it in Repository class where I have `TSource = System` but in Service class I will have `TSource = SystemDto`. I will have to map TSources somehow. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you need a filter method?  Can you not simply call `Where` on your list and specify the properties to filter by at the time?  The alternative would be to write a method with all optional parameters with `null` the default for each. You can then just provide the ones you want each time you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, maybe this helps:

```
///Your Extensions class
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T> ( this IEnumerable<T> src, params Func<T, bool>[] predicates )
    {
        IEnumerator<T> enumerator = src.GetEnumerator();

        while ( enumerator.MoveNext() )
            if ( predicates.All( condition => condition( enumerator.Current ) ) )
                yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
```

Usage:

```
myList = myList.Filter(x => x.Region.Name == "someRegionName",
                       x => x.Application.Name == "someAppName"
                       /*And the list goes on(for the ones you want, duhh)*/
);
```

Or just use what Linq already have:

```
myList = myList.Where(x => x.Region.Name == "someRegionName" &&
                           x.Application.Name == "someAppName"
                           /*And the list goes on(for the ones you want, duhh again)*/
);
```

Or if you have default filters, you can create an extension method class with the default filters, just to evade rewriting tons of repeating filters.

```
public static IEnumerable<MyClass> WhereDefaulted(this IEnumerable<MyClass> src, Func<MyClass,bool> predicate)
{
     return src.Where(x => predicate(x) && 
                           x.Some.Property == "someValue" &&
                           x.Other.Property == 12);
}
```

And then use it:

```
myList = myList.WhereDefaulted(x => x.Some.Other.Property == 'l');
```

Sorry for the poor english.